# Is there a way to run a function both onNext() and onError() without explicitly calling it in both callbacks?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I keep writing code that calls the same cleanup function in both callbacks like this:

```
lockDownStuff();

someHttpClientCall().subscribe((result: any) => {
    handleResult(result);
    unlockStuff();
}, (error: any) => {
    unlockStuff();
});
```

When I really want to call my function that turns off my global spinner, renable form fields, etc. in a fashion more like this:

```
lockDownStuff();

someHttpClientCall().subscribe((result: any) => {
    handleResult(result);
    unlockStuffNoMatterWhat();
});
```

OR

```
someHttpClientCall()
  .subscribe((result: any) => {
    handleResult(result);
  })
  .finally((finally: any) => unlockStuff());
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but have you looked at finalize? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that the observable returned by `someHttpClientCall` is **finite** (meaning that it will emit a *complete* event at some point), you could implement this by using the `finalize` operator as follows:

```
import {finalize} from 'rxjs/operators';

someHttpClientCall()
  .pipe(finalize(()=> unlockStuff()))
  .subscribe(...);
```

If thats not the case, you will need to *transform* the **infinite** stream into a **finite** one, for example by conditionally taking emissions of it until some condition is meet by using `takeUntil`:

```
import {finalize, takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';

someHttpClientCall()
  .pipe(
     takeUntil(....),
     finalize(()=> unlockStuff())
  ).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've elected to use `pipe(take(1), finalize(...))` because I'm doing a HttpClient.get() under the hood. The `take` may be unnecessary if HttpClient.get() returns an Observable that completes automatically, but I don't think it does..

Comment: Its unnecessary, the underlying observable completes after the response is received https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L217